# Plotting using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am a bit confused on how to plot the following data:

```
url          1999         2000               2001
 
url1         20/01/1999   03/01/2000         NaN
url1         21/01/1999   NaN                NaN
url1         23/01/1999   NaN                NaN
url2         12/01/1999   NaN                12/01/2001
url2         13/03/1999   NaN                22/01/2001
url2         14/03/1999   NaN                24/10/2001
```

I would like to plot in different bar charts the urls through time, so something like this:

```
url1         1999(plotting data by month in 1999)     2000 (plotting data by month in 2000)
url2         1999     2001
...
```

(the below is just for an example)

[image]

I am trying to grouping first by urls, then by month per each column, but probably I am doing it in the wrong way:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
data.groupby(['url','1999','2000','2001']).count().plot(ax=ax)
```

I have data until 2020 (so the columns in groupby should be until 2020, though in the example I just wrote the first three for simplicity).

Can you please tell me what would be the right way to use groupby in my case?

Comment: What do the bars represent? And how do you want to present `url` in the plot?

Comment: The bar should be the count of date in one column by month, so for example: 12/01/1999, 13/01/1999, 14/01/1999 (i.e. 3) for one url. It would be also good to represent url in different plot (otherwise I should consider stacked bars, I guess). I was considering to create for each url a different dataset, but the problem is still in plotting data by months per year (or just per year, if it is too complicated by months)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
s = df.melt('url', var_name='year', value_name='date').dropna();
s['month'] = pd.to_datetime(s['date']).dt.month

plot_df = pd.crosstab([s['url'],s['month']], s['year'])

for url in plot_df.index.unique('url'):
    plot_df.loc[url].plot.bar(subplots=True,sharex=True,sharey=True, layout=(1,-1))
    plt.show()
```

And you would get different plots like these:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Quang Hoang. I would have a question: how did you get all the years (as they are within columns)?

Comment: because I use `melt`, which turns part of column names into a column. Print `s` in the above code to see the years.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got this error: ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array I date, because of `s['month'] = pd.to_datetime(s['date']).dt.month`. However I converted dates using datetime

Comment: Those are values in your data. You may have some integers mixed with the dates aside from the `NaN` values. My code only handles `NaN` values as they show up in the sample data.

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang. I will try to identify the integer values, then. I should have had only NaN values and date values. Very weird this message. Thanks again for your help